# PHP regex to allow only two chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need a regex to recognize only two options, they are 'F' and 'M' chars. I am trying:

```
preg_replace('/([^FM]){1}/', '', $_GET['option'])
```

But if i type 'MF' it returns 'MF', but i am expecting 'M'.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why are you expecting `M`? Why not `F`?

Comment: do you want to eliminate all MF ??

Comment: @m.buettner, This var cames from GET so i am trying to validate it, removing all but 'F' and 'M'. If i get 'MF' i will recognize the first valid option readed, 'M' in this case.

Comment: with m/f and $_GET[] i think that you want to check if a value submitted on a form is either male or female? If this is correct, you can better check without regexes, f.e if in_array('m',f);

Comment: At this point you should probably just use `option == 'M' || option == 'F'`... this is not a very good use of regular expressions.

Comment: @NullPointer, Please see the above answer.

Comment: @MarcioSimao i believe answer above is right since  user gave answer is experienced user

Comment: @HeeroYuy, You are right, i am validating if the submited option is male (M) or female (F). I am trying to use regex to prevent PHP Injection, do you think in_array() is secure?

Comment: why regex? why don't you just validate with a simple `if (($_GET['option'] =="F" or ($_GET['option'] =="F")`

Comment: @luchosrock, I am trying to prevent PHP Injection

Comment: @marcio Simao, yes. the array only contains items you specify, plus its binary safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output = preg_replace('/^[^FM]*([FM])?.*/s', '$1', $_GET['option']);
```

Start at the beginning of the string. Consume all non-`FM` characters. Then match one `F` or `M` character (if there is one). Match the rest of the input. Replace with the matched character. Note that you will end up with an empty string if there was no `M` or `F` at all.

However, you should probably rethink how you get that data, since it seems to be a boolean value (but you take care of an arbitrary string that might contain the desired characters).

If you generate the value yourself (from some other website), you should be able to know that values that haven't been tampered with are either `"M"` or `"F"`. So why not just go with:

```
if ($_GET['option'] == "M")
    // male...
elseif ($_GET['option'] == "F")
    // female...
else
    // someone tried to mess with you ...
```

Comment: I am trying to prevent PHP Injection, do you know if your second suggestion is secure? Thanks!

Comment: @MarcioSimao as long as you don't use the value of `$_GET['option']` anywhere outside the `male` and `female` block you should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Could always try this. It's a one liner and will grab the first character of the string. If 'm' or 'M' it will return 'M'. and same goes for female. If nothing matches then it will return ''.

`$gender = strtolower(substr($_GET['option'], 0, 1)) == 'f' ? 'F' : (strtolower(substr($_GET['option'], 0, 1)) == 'm' ? 'M' : '');`